# Angularjs ng-style with interpolation expression

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

### Angularjs v1.5.9 : ng-style (ngStyle)

There's a simple **div** with **ng-style** command in my directive template, and I use a interpolation expression to get different style at run time:

```
<div class="large-1 tile tile-plain"
      ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype]}}.png)'}">
</div>
```

The directive as follow:

```
 .directive('knowledgeItemIcon', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'templates/item-icon.html',
          scope: {
            item: '='
          },
          link: function (scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.iconMap = {
              'howto': 'pen',
              'reference': 'settings',
              //...
            };
          }
        };
      });
```

The **iconMap** is an static array defined in the directive's link function.
And **docktype** is a property of item in the scope.

But when the template render to the browser, I got:

```
<knowledge-item-icon item="vm.item" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div class="large-1 tile tile-plain" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-phone.png)'} style="background-image: url("assets/images/km-types/ico-.png");">
    </div>
</knowledge-item-icon>
```

In **ng-style** it seems got the right string where is ico-phone.png , but null in **style** attribute.
I checked both the item and iconMap object are not undefined, but why I got this difference in the web application?

---

Currently I add a **img** node with **ng-src** command in the div element like:

```
<img ng-src="assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype] || default}}.png" alt="">
```

It could translate to the correct string:

```
<img ng-src="assets/images/km-types/ico-phone.png" alt="" src="assets/images/km-types/ico-phone.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to write complicated HTML I suggest you to use style method or value

```
<div class="large-1 tile tile-plain"
      ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype]}}.png)'}">
</div>
```

Goes to be:

```
<div class="large-1 tile tile-plain"
     ng-style="getStyle(item.doctype)">
{{candidate.name}}
</div>
```

where `getStyle` is:

```
$scope.getStyle = function(type){
  return {
    'background-image': "url(assets/images/km-types/ico-" + iconMap[type] + ".png)"    
  }      
}
```

Its more clear way

<kbd>[some Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3px97ma0/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But according to some test I found that the **iconMap** object (defined in the link function) may be undefined when the interpolation excuted, because in the **style** tag(guess it was translated from *ng-style*) got the iconMap is null. But what puzzling is that when application is running in browser, *ng-style* can get the **iconMap** object.
May be related to execution order or different lifecycle between the *link* function and  interpolation expression or any other..... don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `ng-style` tag.

**Change**

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype]}}.png)''}">
```

**to**

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype]}}.png)'}">
```

See the example below.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

  $scope.item = {
    "doctype": "test"
  }

  $scope.iconMap = {
    "test": "test-image"
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

  <div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype]}}.png)'}">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh, the typo may caused by copy from my editor, sorry for the mistake. 
And I try to run a simple demo like your example, it works fine. But in the product it can be a little complicated.

Comment: Reason to not work `ng-style` properly is `"{'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-{{iconMap[item.doctype]}}.png)''}"`  two single quotes at the end of url parenthesis. I think it's also in your editor and not a copy paste mistake.

Comment: Finally I concatenated the URL string in a function in the scope and return to the *ng-style*, it will be work properly.
-------------------------------------
scope.getIcon = function(){
return {
            'background-image': 'url(assets/images/km-types/ico-'+scope.iconMap[scope.item.doctype]+'.png)'
}

Comment: Two quotes in the code may cause Lexer Error in the browser, its really a mistake when I copying from the VS Code parted.